# error while opening CHM after compiling help using doxygen

Tags: doxygen, chm, doxywizard

I am recently getting the following error while opening CHM file generated by Doxywizard version 1.8.16.

On a Win 7 m/c, I get the following error on all pages:

```
 '$' is undefined
```

for every page.

it comes from the following line in index.html

```
$(function() {
  initMenu('',false,false,'search.php','Search');
});
```

---

**UPDATED LATER:**

On a Win 10 m/c, i didn't get the above error, but a different error in some pages in the CHM as follows :

```
Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
```

This error happens within the *jquery.js* file.

--
Diff of configuration is the following (note that I have replaced some names with '...'):

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.16 (cfd73d5c4d1a66c620a3b7c08b72a3f3c3f9
255*)
PROJECT_NAME           = ...
PROJECT_NUMBER         = x.y.z.w
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "..."
PROJECT_LOGO           = .../....png
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
SHOW_USED_FILES        = NO
INPUT                  = ../src/ \
                         ../src/main.c \
                         ...
                         ...
                         ../docs/....md \
                         \docs
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *.c \
                         *.h
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
GENERATE_DOCSET        = YES
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = YES
CHM_FILE               = mydoc.chm
HHC_LOCATION           = "C:/Program Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop/hhc.exe"
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
LATEX_MAKEINDEX_CMD    = \makeindex
INCLUDE_PATH           = ../include
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
DOT_PATH               = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin"
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with with version 1.8.16. In the index.html I do see the mentioned code but when running the hhc executable in doxygen it produces no errors. Do you have any special configuration settings (use `doxygen -x` to see the differences with the default Doxyfile) and add the result to the question (in text form not an attachment). Also add a small example of the code producing the problem.

Comment: @albert I don't know how to get the command-line parameters that doxywizard is using at the backend.

Comment: You will have a directory where the code to document resides as well as the Doxyfile and the resulting html output (the html irectory is the directory where you found the index.html). You can give the mentioned command in a terminal /command window at the directory where the Doxyfile is.

Comment: @albert: thanks. i think my windows not been able to run the jquery code. when i open it using sumatrapdf. it opens and renders properly. what could be the issue.

Comment: I don't get the comment about sumatrapdf in relation to a chm  file.

Comment: sumatrapdf is a software which can open chm files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200448/discussion-between-user62039-and-albert).

Comment: I didn't know that sumatrapdf could handle chm files (seen the program name, but its documentation says it can). Strange that there is a problem with jquery as it is not included explicitly but implicitly (at least I don't see it in the `hhp` file, but it looks like to be in the resulting chm file. How did you deduct that jquery is the problem? When I comment the mentioned function the jquery is still in.Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: What's about opening the resulting CHM by using the Windows default viewer (wrapper) HH.exe?

Comment: I get the error as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: @albert Win 7 gives above error. ON Win 10 however , I get different error in other pages. (See original post updated)

Comment: @help-info.de isn't the hh.exe the default application that is used in case of double click? Of course the `chm` extension might be "redirected" so it is worthwhile to give it a try.

Comment: @albert I was wondering about the use of SumatraPDF on a Windows System. It's a different viewer appalso for use on Linux - AFAIK. I can't reproduce the error described by OP.